# Changing circle to "-stealth"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I took an example from pgfplots

```
% Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
% [See the TikZ manual if you’d like to learn about nodes and pins]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
     every pin/.style={fill=yellow!50!white,rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,font=\tiny},
     small dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.3}
  }
  \begin{axis}[
              clip=false,
              title=How \texttt{axis description cs} works
  ]
  \addplot {x};
  \node[small dot,pin=120:{$(0,0)$}] at (axis description cs:0,0) {};
  \node[small dot,pin=-30:{$(1,1)$}] at (axis description cs:1,1) {};
  \node[small dot,pin=-90:{$(1.03,0.5)$}] at (axis description cs:1.03,0.5) {};
  \node[small dot,pin=125:{$(0.5,0.5)$}] at (axis description cs:0.5,0.5) {};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I would like to place an arrow (-stealth’) instead of a circle and to be able to control the thickness.

Comment: Could you place an image of the plot that the code you have provided generates into the question please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TikZ manual's section `The pin option` explains how to control `pin` and `pin edge` styles.
Here you have some examples with your code. If you don't want `dots` on you labeled points, delete `small dot` option from every node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
     every pin/.style={fill=yellow!50!white,rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,font=\tiny},
     small dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.3},
      every pin edge/.style={<-,>=stealth'},
      mypinedgestyle/.style={<-,>=stealth',dashed,green, very thick}
  }
  \begin{axis}[
              clip=false,
              title=How \texttt{axis description cs} works
  ]
  \addplot {x};
  \node[small dot,pin={[pin edge={<-,>=stealth',red,very thick}]120:{$(0,0)$}}] at (axis description cs:0,0) {};
  \node[small dot,pin={[pin edge={mypinedgestyle}]-30:{$(1,1)$}}] at (axis description cs:1,1) {};
  \node[small dot,pin=-90:{$(1.03,0.5)$}] at (axis description cs:1.03,0.5) {};
  \node[small dot,pin=125:{$(0.5,0.5)$}] at (axis description cs:0.5,0.5) {};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the `pin` option probably isn't ideal. Since it puts a node on the location you want an arrow at. It's probably possible using a decoration or a custom node shape, but in my opinion it's not the easiest solution. The easiest solution is to just create a path from the coordinate you want to point at to the node with the information in it. That would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
     every pin/.style={fill=yellow!50!white,rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,font=\tiny},
     small dot/.style={fill=black,-stealth,scale=0.3}
  }
  \begin{axis}[
              clip=false,
              title=How \texttt{axis description cs} works
  ]
  \addplot {x};
  \draw[stealth-, very thin] (axis description cs:0,0) -- ++(140:1cm) node[every pin]{$(0,0)$};
  \draw[stealth-, very thin] (axis description cs:1,1) -- ++(-40:1cm) node[every pin]{$(1,1)$};
  \draw[stealth-, very thin] (axis description cs:1.03,0.5) -- ++(-90:1cm) node[every pin]{$(1.03,0.5)$};
  \draw[stealth-, very thin] (axis description cs:0.5,0.5) -- ++(125:1cm) node[every pin]{$(0.5,0.5)$};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the resulting picture:

[image: image with arrows]